# iPhone -SQLite: Display decimal values separated by coma (",")

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sqlite, ios4

In iPhone app I want to print Decimal values separated by ","

i.e.2392890 should appear as 2,392,890

I am fetching these numbers from a SQLite database

Answer (score 0):

This is [solution](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/5235-decimal-number-format.html)

```
//American number format - with comma sepparators between thousands
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[numberFormatter setFormat:@"#,###"];
NSNumber *averageResponseTime = [NSNumber numberWithInt:123456789];

//If you print next thing
[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ms",[numberFormatter stringForObjectValue:averageResponseTime]];

//You will get 123,456,789
```

Comment: It is giving Worning NSNumberFormattor may not respond to SetFormat

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: iOS Note: iOS supports only the modern 10.4+ behavior. 10.0-style methods and format strings are not available on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your number to following function to get Formatted output.

```
-(NSString*)getFormattedString:(double)pDoubleValue
{
    NSNumber *doubleNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:pDoubleValue];
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSString *formattedOutput = [formatter stringFromNumber:doubleNumber];
    [formatter release];
    return formattedOutput;
}
```

hope it helps.